# angular universal ReferenceError navigator is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am trying to implement server side rendering in my application.

I am following this tutorial: [angular ssr tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-seo-server-side-rendering-with-angular-universal/)

When I execute

```
$ npm run serve:ssr
```

it gives me the following error:

```
> node dist/server

/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:147912
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
                  ^

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at /Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:147912:19
    at VrN/.userAgent (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:147906:28)
    at Object.VrN/ (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:147908:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
    at 1p+/ (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:12054:9)
    at Object.1p+/ (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:12056:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.fvdB (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:209156:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.2M+U (/Users/fbarril/forms-builder/dist/server/main.js:39968:24)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! egoi-landing-page-builder@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the egoi-landing-page-builder@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/fbarril/.npm/_logs/2020-01-07T10_26_15_252Z-debug.log
```

I know that I can't access navigator while using server side rendering but **main.js** is a generated file.
If you need additional info let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Server side rendering does not understand navigator like in ur case node.js don't understand navigator. so create service and use navigator there. then server will understand.

Comment: main.js is a generated file. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Navigator is window object, and hence if you are intended to make use in browser, you can add a server check, [use this](https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformServer)

```
if (this.isPlatformBrowser(platformId)){
   // Use Navigator
}
```

And based on it you can run the navigator in browser alone.